# ManyToMany Relationship Unable to Delete Parent

Tags: java, java-8

I have below code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee  {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_details_id")
    private List<EmployeeDetails> employeemployeeDetails;

}  



@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_details")
public class EmployeeDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long employee_details_id;


  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "employee_details-employee")
  private List<Employee> employees;
}
```

When I am trying to delete with below code

```
EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = <already have object>;

if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(employeeDetails.getEmployee())) {
    employeeDetails.getEmployee().removeAll(employeeDetails.getEmployee());
    employeeDetails = empolyeeDetailsRepository.save(employeeDetails);
}
empolyeeDetailsRepository.delete(employeeDetails);
```

It gives below error

**ERROR: update or delete on table "employee_details" violates foreign key constraint "fk28fdh1drqsj72rg16lctbje88" on table "employee_employee_details" Detail: Key (employee_details_id)=(XX) is still referenced from table "employee_employee_details".**

How to delete child & parent?

Comment: You might want to share `Employee` as well. Note that `mappedBy = "employeeDetails"` indicates that `Employee` is the actual owner of the details so you need to remove the details from the employee first and _persist_ that change (e.g. call `save()` for the employee).

Comment: Btw. `employeeDetails.getEmployee().removeAll(employeeDetails.getEmployee());` looks odd. This would indicate a method like `Employee.removeAll(Employee)`...

Comment: Java what? There is no @ManyToMany annotation in Java JDK, you are missing the framework

Comment: Added details in the questions.

Comment: @Jackson what are the details? You are using Hibernate? Maybe yes. Maybe add this annotation can solve your problem `@Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)`

Comment: Tried `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference(value = "employee_details-employee")
@Cascade(value = org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private List<Employee> employees;` Still same error @vincenzopalazzo